# How to output a complex plot with settings from a matlab function

Tags: function, matlab, plot, output, figure

I wrote a matlab script, part of which is a plot

```
  graph = plot(fT, 'k', space, prediction_tactile);
  set(graph(1), 'Color', 'k','linestyle', 'none', 'Marker', 'o')
  set(graph(2),'linewidth',3);
  hold on
  graph_2 = plot(fV, 'r', space, prediction_visual);
  
  set(graph_2(1), 'Color','r','linestyle', 'none', 'Marker', 'o')
  set(graph_2(2),'linewidth',3);
 
  xline(rough_stimulus, '--k', {'Stimulus 1','roughness'});  
  xline(fine_stimulus, '--r', {'Stimulus 2','roughness'}); 
  legend('Stimulus_1 response data', 'Stimulus_1 response distribution', 'Stimulus_2 response data', 'Stimulus_2 response distribution')
  ylabel ('Probability', 'FontSize',16,'FontWeight','bold','Color','k')
  xlabel ('Arbitrary roughness space', 'FontSize',16,'FontWeight','bold','Color','k')
  title ('Perceived roughness simulation','FontSize',20,'FontWeight','bold')
 hold off
```

Now I try to convert the script to the function  `[figure,pC] = BCI_vic_att (noise)` to run in a loop (I need multiple plots ) so I have output 25 figures. But I am completely baffled how to output this plot to the workspace.
Will be very grateful for help

Answer (score 2):

if you have a for loop just add `figure` before your code:

```
for n=1:25

    figure(n)

        %your code 

end
```

**dont** use `figure` as a variable name. it's a matlab built in function.

If you insist on making a function out of your script, then what is the input to the function, and what is it suppose to output besides the figure ? (there are a lot of plot inputs there `fT`, `space`, `prediction_tactile`, etc...

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment. The script calculates (simulates) all the values from a couple of inputs, like noise and std and mean of the distribution. I give it the parameters of distributions ( std and means) and the noise

Comment: I counted 5 inputs to the script you wrote:, fT, space, prediction_tactile, rough_stimulus, fine_stimulus . I didnt see std or mean .

Comment: These are values calculated by the script, that plot uses. It actually visualises the perception of stimuli that human may experience. So I give it the parameters of several distributions (that describe the stimulus) and plot the hypothetical perception. I have a lot of participants with individual noise levels , so I wanted to automate it a lot

Comment: i dont know what is your question then. there is no mention in the code of any of the parameters (noise, mean, std)  that are the inputs to the function you want to make.